# How do you plot information from a dataframe based on the categorical data within the rows?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

[Output of df.describe()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waFbl.png)

I am trying to plot a scatterplot using certain categorical information from a DataFrame, within the column 'Equipment'. I want to plot only the rows where the df['Equipment'] == 'Raw'. I have tried to use an if statement, but have come across an error.

Here is the if statement I used,

```
if df.Equipment == 'Raw':
     plt.scatter(df['Bench'], df['Total'])
plt.show()
```

Here is the error code,

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2869/841785767.py in <module>
----> 1 if df.Equipment == 'Raw':
      2     plt.scatter(df['Bench'], df['Total'])
      3 plt.show()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1535     @final
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1537         raise ValueError(
   1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: the answer should be separate from the question...

Answer (score 0):

**MY SOLUTION**

I found a good work-around for my problem. I instead create a new DataFrame. The main problem was trying to use the conditional statement on a string instead of a value. The code I used is,

```
df_raw = df[df.Equipment.str.contains('Raw',case=False)]
```

Here is a link to the website that helped me handle my problem, it has other good useful solutions to similar problems too.

https://kanoki.org/2019/03/27/pandas-select-rows-by-condition-and-string-operations/